use different y values defined in another file
I have two py files named: randomvar.py and test_Random.py in the same folder.
The file randomvar.py is given below:
import numpy as np
from test_Random import call_random

def evaluate_expressions(expressions, x):
    def evaluate_expression(expr, x):
        return eval(expr)

    # Evaluate each expression in the list
    results = [evaluate_expression(expr, x) for expr in expressions]
    return results

f = ['x[0]**2*y+x[1]', 'x[0]-y*x[1]']

def func(x):
    return evaluate_expressions(f, x)

x = np.array([1,2])

call_random(func, x)

And the file test_Random.py is given below:
import numpy as np

yy=np.array([3,4])
def call_random(ff, x):
    for i in range(2):
        y = yy[i]
        z = ff(x)
        print(z)

Note that the files are separated (for personal purposes). What I wanted to do is
to use the value y=yy[i] in test_Random.py every time I call the function call_random(func, x) in the randomvar.py. What should I change to achieve this?

To solve your problem, use yield in the call_random function. This code should do what you want:
In test_Random.py:
import numpy as np

yy=np.array([1,2])
def call_random(ff, x):
    for i in range(2):
        y = yy[i]
        yield y
        z = ff(x)
        print(z)

In randomvar.py:
import numpy as np
from test_Random import call_random

def evaluate_expressions(expressions, x):
    def evaluate_expression(expr, x):
        return eval(expr)

    # Evaluate each expression in the list
    results = [evaluate_expression(expr, x) for expr in expressions]
    return results

f = ['x[0]**2*y+x[1]', 'x[0]-y*x[1]']

def func(x):
    return evaluate_expressions(f, x)

x = np.array([1,2])

for i in call_random(func, x):
    print(i)

You can also place the yield y line after the print() call, depending on what you want the behavior of call_random to be. Also, the for-loop in randomvar.py is just a demo of what the call_random function will behave. Basically, the loop variable i will be the value of y.

Thank you Luke! But I tried and it not print out any thing. Could you please double check ?
